# Why doesn't this jQuery image map not work on WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, genesis

Hello I have made a jQuery image map on codepen but when I transfer it to my clients WordPress install it no longer works?

The WordPress site is made with genesis and I thought that may be causing the problem... I also replaced `$` with `jQuery` to stop conflict problems.

Pen: http://codepen.io/naniio/pen/QwVXWG

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery(".clickable").click(function() {
       var toHide = $(this).attr('data-hide');
       jQuery(".map").toggle();
       jQuery("#" + toHide).toggle();
   });

   jQuery(".hide").click(function() {
       jQuery(".map").toggle();
       jQuery(this).toggle();
   });
```

});

Site www.shakesafe.co.nz

I added the code (HTML + JS) the home page with simple hooks and then added the CSS with a custom body tag for the home page in gensis samples stylesheet.. but the Jquery doesn't work? do you guys have any ideas as to why?

Thanks for your time and effort as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always** check your browser console for errors thrown. In this case, I see a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` message. That error is found on line 112 on your page, and if you check it carefully, you are using the `$` without assigning the jQuery object to it, hence causing an error:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(".clickable").click(function() {
       var toHide = $(this).attr('data-hide');  // Line 112 where error is from
         jQuery(".map").toggle();
         jQuery("#"+toHide).toggle();
    });

     jQuery(".hide").click(function() {
       jQuery(".map").toggle();
       jQuery(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Replace the `$` with `jQuery`, i.e. `var toHide = jQuery(this).attr('data-hide');`.

Alternatively, you can tell jQuery that you are using `$` to stand in for the jQuery object, saving you 5 characters every single instance you call for it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".clickable").click(function() {
       var toHide = $(this).attr('data-hide');
         $(".map").toggle();
         $("#"+toHide).toggle();
    });

     $(".hide").click(function() {
       $(".map").toggle();
       $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it's because of $ on 3rd line:
var toHide = $(this).attr('data-hide');

Try changing it to jQuery. It may work.

Also your site had no $ on your code:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

try putting $ between small braces after function

Comment: That's not true — OP has already delegated the `$` to the jQuery object (in the first line, `jQuery(document).ready(function($)...`), so using `$` to stand in for the jQuery object should have no issue.

Comment: @Terry Your answer is more elaborated form of mine. Please check my answer well before commenting it not true.